# Profiting on merchandise

Tags: halacha

Is it a sin to over charge on merchandise, say a movie costs 5 dollars but I sell it for 20. Of course some of that goes to expenses.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/40180

Comment: I see, so it's market value

Answer (score 1):

No. The definition of Ona'ah, or charging more than the market price, is defined by the market price. The reason why is because the ability to charge a high price encourages people to supply said asset.

What would be forbidden is restraining competition to enable you to charge an unreasonably high price.